# How can we store a sound file (from Url) into Ram memory in Dart / Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, storage, ram, audio-player

I have sound files stored on AppWrite storage. These files are downloadable via URL.
I want to play them using Audioplayers(). When I put the Url directly with Audioplayers, there's a delay when user taps button. I don't want that. I want it to be immediate.
That's why, I would like to download the file first, store it in memory, and then play the "variable" which holds the file with AudioPlayers().

Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`storage.getFileDownload()`](https://appwrite.io/docs/client/storage?sdk=apple-default#storageGetFileDownload) to pre-emptively download the file. On Flutter, this returns the bytes as `Uint8List` that you can store into state or device storage.